# Custom field in onepage checkout - how to save to database

Tags: checkout, event-observer, magento-1, quote

I am trying to add a custom field containing the `deliverydate` to the checkout of Magento. However I have problems saving it. I have added the field to the `shipping_method` page and set up an observer in the `config.xml`:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShippingMethod>
            <observers>
                <mymodule_deliverydate>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>mymodule_deliverydate/observer</class>
                    <method>saveDeliverydate</method>
                </mymodule_deliverydate>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShippingMethod>
    </events>

</frontend>
```

Also, the quote to order conversion is set up in the `config.xml`:

```
<global>
....
<fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <deliverydate>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </deliverydate>
            </sales_convert_quote>
        </fieldsets>
</global>
```

I have added a field `deliverydate` to the `sales_flat_order` table ( and `sales_flat_quote` but Im not too sure if that was necessary) and set up the observer function like this:

```
public function saveDeliverydate($observer)
    {

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    $deliverydate = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('deliverydate');

    if(!empty($deliverydate))
    {
        $order->setDeliverydate($deliverydate);
    }
}
```

However when the order has been placed, the field is empty in the database. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MAY THIS ASNWER WILL HELP YOU TO SOLVE YOUR ISSUE**

CHANGE YOU EVENTS TO:

```
  <events>
            <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
                <observers>
                    <deliverydate_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>deliverydate/observer</class>
                        <method>checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method</method>
                    </deliverydate_observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <order_set_shippingarrivaldate>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>deliverydate/observer</class>
                        <method>saveShippingArrivalDate</method>
                    </order_set_shippingarrivaldate>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
        </events>
```

THEN IN OBSERVER:

```
public function checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method($observer)
        {
                $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
                $quote =  $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

                $desiredArrivalDate = $request->getPost('deliverydate', '');
                if (isset($desiredArrivalDate) && !empty($desiredArrivalDate)){
                    $quote->setdeliverydate($desiredArrivalDate);

                    $quote->save();
                }


            return $this;
        }
 public function saveShippingArrivalDate($observer){

            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $desiredArrivalDate = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('deliverydate');
            if (isset($desiredArrivalDate) && !empty($desiredArrivalDate)){

                $order->setdeliverydate($desiredArrivalDate);

        }
```

IF ABOVE saveShippingArrivalDate DOESNT WORK THEN YOU USE BELOW CODE FOR THAT FUNCTION

```
 public function saveShippingArrivalDate($observer){  $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData();
                $desiredArrivalDate =$cart['deliverydate'];

                if (isset($desiredArrivalDate) && !empty($desiredArrivalDate)){

                    $order->setdeliverydate($desiredArrivalDate);
                }
    }
```